# How to output an array of values using a function, "For" loop, and two existing arrays in Excel VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I'm in an entry-level engineering computations course. I'm stuck on a problem using loops and arrays.

The goal is to use a single function and a "For" or "Do" loop to calculate the squared difference between two sets of 10 values at one time.

The data / arrays are in two rows, as shown:

[image: two rows of data]

Essentially, we're solving for (A1-B1)^2 in cell A3, (A2-B2)^2 in cell B3, etc.

The code that I was able to work out runs but will only display the correct function value for the final column's data, since (9-1)^2 = 64, as shown:

[image: failed code execution]

```vb
Option Base 1
Public Function SqDiff(arrayA As Range, arrayB As Range) As Variant
Dim ncell As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim A As Single
Dim B As Single
Dim SquareDifference As Single
For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
    A = arrayA(i)
    B = arrayB(i)
    SquareDifference = (A - B) ^ 2
    SqDiff = SquareDifference
Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the UDF as an array formula, you need to return `SqDiff` as an array as well:

```
Public Function SqDiff(arrayA As Range, arrayB As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim A As Single
    Dim B As Single
    Dim SquareDifference As Single

    'Make sure that the input ranges are of 1 row size and same amount of cells
    If arrayA.Rows.Count = 1 And arrayB.Rows.Count = 1 And arrayA.Cells.Count = arrayB.Cells.Count Then
        'Assign the ranges' value into an array for faster processing
        Dim arrA As Variant
        arrA = arrayA.Value
        
        Dim arrB As Variant
        arrB = arrayB.Value
        
        'Create a temp array of the same size as the input size, to assign to SqDiff later
        Dim output() As Variant
        ReDim output(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arrA, 2)) As Variant
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrA, 2)
            A = arrA(1, i)
            B = arrB(1, i)
            SquareDifference = (A - B) ^ 2
            output(1, i) = SquareDifference
        Next i
        
        SqDiff = output
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: awesome !!! the output function was what i was missing as well as messing up the rows and columns & forgetting to utilize ncell. your explanation is very comprehensive as well, which helps a lot. thank you !!

Comment: @mixxdup Note - I'm not sure if you really need to make a UDF for this purpose as you can e.g. based on your sample, insert the formula `=(A1-A2)^2` in cell A3 then fill down the rest of the cells.... You don't exactly need to make a UDF and apply array formula to achieve what you want in your example.

Comment: that would be a much simpler way to do it, but our teacher told us to use a UDF and either an "if" or "do" loop to find the solutions

Answer (score 1):

### UDF - Array Formula

- If you don't have Office 365, you need to enter the formula as an array formula
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You select the range, but enter the formula only into the first cell.
- Note that all three ranges have to be of the same size.

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function SqDiff( _
    ByVal RangeA As Range, _
    ByVal RangeB As Range) _
As Double()

    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = RangeA.Rows.Count
    If rCount <> RangeB.Rows.Count Then Exit Function
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = RangeA.Columns.Count
    If cCount <> RangeB.Columns.Count Then Exit Function

    Dim aData As Variant, bData As Variant
    If rCount + cCount = 2 Then ' one cell
        ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): aData(1, 1) = RangeA.Value
        ReDim bData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): bData(1, 1) = RangeB.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        aData = RangeA.Value
        bData = RangeB.Value
    End If
    
    Dim Data() As Double: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            If IsNumeric(aData(r, c)) Then
                If IsNumeric(bData(r, c)) Then
                    ' Choose/modify the operation.
                    Data(r, c) = (aData(r, c) - bData(r, c)) ^ 2
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
        
    SqDiff = Data

End Function
```